# How to apply an if at compile time in C++

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to write a general `static_for` implementation that can accept bounds, an increment function & a comparison function to run a loop through. I have been using this construct with simple loops that increment by 1. In that case it is easy to stop the loop unrolling by simply specializing on the `IDX & END` being equal.

However when the increment could be with an arbitrary integer, it is not guaranteed that the `IDX & END` will always be equal. The `if` conditional is only evaluated at run time. In the code snippet below I was trying to specialize on the `std::false_type` which stops the recursion. The integral_constant is constructed by evaluating the `std::less` functional (which could be substituted by the user for any other evaluation). Unfortunately this `comparator` functional is also evaluated only at run time and therefore the compiler fails. Could someone advise on how to get this to work?

**NOTE**: Using C++11.

```
template <int idx, int end, typename eval, int count, typename comparator>
struct static_for_loop {
  template <typename Lambda, typename... Args>
  void operator()(const Lambda& function, Args... args) const {
    if (comparator()(idx, end)) {
      std::integral_constant<int, idx> i;

      function(i, args...);

      constexpr bool lesser = comparator()(idx + count, end);
      static_for_loop<idx + count, end, std::integral_constant<bool, lesser>, count,
                      comparator>()(function, args...);
    }
  }
};

template <int idx, int end, int count, typename comparator>
struct static_for_loop<idx, end, std::false_type, count, comparator> {
  template <typename Lambda, typename... Args>
  void operator()(const Lambda& function, Args... args) const {}
};

template <int idx, int end, int count = 1, typename comparator = std::less<int>>
struct static_for {
  template <typename Lambda, typename... Args>
  void operator()(const Lambda& function, Args... args) const {
    static_for_loop<idx, end, std::true_type, count, comparator>()(function, args...);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it easier to just wrap everything in an object:

```
template <int S, int E, int step>
struct iter {
    auto next() { return iter<std::min(E, S+step), E, step>{}; }
};
```

And then you just have an overload for the case where it's done and the case where it's not:

```
template <int S, int E, int step, class F, class... Args>
void for_loop(iter<S, E, step> i, F func, Args... args) {
    func(S, args...);

    for_loop(i.next(), func, args...);
}

template <int E, int step, class F, class... Args>
void for_loop(iter<E, E, step>, F, Args... ) {
}
```

For instance:

```
// prints 0 4 8
for_loop(iter<0, 10, 4>{}, [](int i){std::cout << i << ' ';});
```

---

Alternatively, could use `enable_if` to differentiate the cases to avoid the need for `min`:

```
template <int S, int E, int step, class F, class... Args>
std::enable_if_t<(S<E)> for_loop(iter<S, E, step>, F func, Args... args)
{
    func(S, args...);
    for_loop(iter<S+step, E, step>{}, func, args...);
}

template <int S, int E, int step, class F, class... Args>
std::enable_if_t<!(S<E)> for_loop(iter<S, E, step>, F , Args... )
{
}
```

YMMV on which you prefer.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add I am still using C++11. That would be a great solution for C++14 with generic lambdas.

Comment: @AmmarHusain You don't really need C++14 for any of this, just some convenience shorthands.

Comment: Yes the enable_if would work. I am going to give it a try now.

Comment: I am unable to compile your proposed code. It has a problem with the enable_if usage.       Here is what I get from clang: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false, void>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration

Comment: @AmmarHusain Not sure how you mean. Here's a [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12e618548a31b3bf) that works in C++11.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sfinae to overcome the problem:

```
template <int idx, int end, typename eval, int count, typename Comparator>
struct static_for_loop {
    template <typename Lambda, typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Lambda&& function, Args&&... args) const
    -> std::enable_if_t<Comparator{}(idx, end)> {
        std::integral_constant<int, idx> i;

        std::forward<Lambda>(function)(i, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        constexpr bool lesser = comparator{}(idx + count, end);

        static_for_loop<
            idx + count,
            END,
            std::integral_constant<bool, lesser>,
            count,
            Comparator
        >()(std::forward<Lambda>(function), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    // do nothing when false
    template <typename Lambda, typename... Args>
    auto operator()(Lambda&& function, Args&&... args) const
    -> std::enable_if_t<!Comparator{}(idx, end)> {

    }
};
```

`std::enable_if` will select the right function with sfinae. It will act as a compile time if.

I used perfect forwarding too, as your code didn't work in all case, like passing non copiable or a mutable lambda. Now it will.

If you do not have c++14, you can write `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` instead.

Try to use less all uppercase name, it hurts lisibility.

Comment: I am unable to compile your proposed code. It has a problem with the enable_if usage. Here is what I get from clang: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false, void>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration

Comment: Try update your compiler. Note that you should provide both function, one with the `!` in the enable if  and one without.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the problem that you are underspecifying `comparator`? Just specify your API such that `comparator<IDX>::type` is `std::true_type` if the loop should continue for `IDX`, and stop when it's `false_type`. Your simple loop case then uses `template<int IDX> using Comp = std::integral_constant<bool, (IDX < 5`)>`.